# Unexpected behaviour when testing equality with naive and tz-aware datetime instances

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone, comparison

The following was produced in Python 3.9.7.

I am well aware that the comparison between tz-aware and naive `datetime` instances is not allowed in Python and raises a `TypeError`. However, when testing for equality (with the `==` and `!=` operators) this is actually not the case. In fact, the comparison always returns `False`:

```
import datetime
import pytz

t_tz_aware = datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 23, tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
t_naive = datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 23)

# Prints 'False'.
print(t_tz_aware == t_naive)

# Raises TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes.
print(t_tz_aware < t_naive)
```

I checked the [source code of the `datetime` library](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/354ace8b07e7d445fd2de713b6af1271536adce0/Lib/datetime.py#L2024) and the function for comparing datetime objects has a parameter called `allow_mixed` (which defaults to `False`):

```
def _cmp(self, other, allow_mixed=False)
```

When set to `True`, which is the case when comparing using the `==` operator, it is possible to compare tz-aware and naive `datetime` instances. Otherwise, it raises a TypeError:

```
# When testing for equality, set allow_mixed to True.
# For all the other operators, it remains False.
def __eq__(self, other):
   if isinstance(other, datetime):
      return self._cmp(other, allow_mixed=True) == 0
```

```
if myoff is None or otoff is None:
   if allow_mixed:
      return 2 # arbitrary non-zero value
   else:
      raise TypeError("cannot compare naive and aware datetimes")
```

So, it really seems intended behaviour. In fact, Pandas' implementation of the comparisons of `pandas.Timestamps` and similar is consistent with this.

My question is, what is the reasoning? I suppose, like the name of the parameter says, this way we can filter collections of `datetime` objects that contain both naive and tz-aware instances (i.e., "mixed"). But wouldn't this just introduce a source of potential bugs and unintended behaviour? What am I missing?

**EDIT** after deceze's comments:
this is in fact still "semantically correct" (i.e., the dates are for sure different).

Comment: Well, it can certainly tell you that it’s *not the same* (because one has a timezone and the other doesn’t). It can’t tell you whether one is *before* or *after* the other, since the question is meaningless between a naïve and aware date time.

Comment: @deceze right, that is true. I was wondering whether there is a reason to allow it besides it still being "semantically correct". Testing naïve and aware datetime for equality did not seem to apply to sensible scenarios in my mind

Comment: An equality comparison virtually never raises an exception. You just want to test whether two arbitrary objects are equal. Unless they clearly are, the simple answer is “no”, not an error. That’s not the case for greater than/lower than comparisons, for which objects need to be clearly orderable, and “there’s no answer to your question” (i.e. an error) is a viable third result.

Comment: @deceze that is also true. Also, changing this would probably also be very unpythonic. Thanks for the discussion, I was puzzled at first but makes total sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be seen in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fold), up until Python 3.2 a `TypeError` was actually raised in these cases:

> Changed in version 3.3: Equality comparisons between aware and naive
> datetime instances don’t raise TypeError.

In 2012 the Python developers considered the trade-off between these two issues:

- Raising a `TypeError` would make it easier to catch bugs caused by the grave mistake of mixing naive and aware `datetime` objects.
- In Python you can use the equality comparison on virtually any combination of objects. Raising a `TypeError` for `datetime` objects only would break that consistency.

Here's the pertinent discussion on the [Python developer mailing list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-June/119935.html):

> > > > > This is nice when your datetime objects are freshly created. It is not so
> > > > > nice when some of them already exist e.g. in a database (using an ORM
> > > > > layer). Mixing naive and aware datetimes is currently a catastrophe, since
> > > > > even basic operations such as equality comparison fail with a TypeError (it
> > > > > must be pretty much the only type in the stdlib with such poisonous
> > > > > behaviour).
> > > >
> > > > Comparing aware and naive datetime objects doesn't make much sense but
> > > > it's an easy mistake to make. I would say the TypeError is a sensible
> > > > way to warn you while simply returning False could lead to much
> > > > confusion.
> > >
> > > You could say the same about equally "confusing" results, yet equality never
> > > raises TypeError (except between datetime instances):
> > >
> > > ```
> > > >>> () == []
> > > False
> > > ```
> > >
> > > Raising an exception has very serious implications, such as making it
> > > impossible to put these objects in the same dictionary.
> >
> > And even closer to home,
> >
> > ```
> > >>> date(2012,6,1) == datetime(2012,6,1)
> > `False`
> > ```
> >
> > I agree, equality comparison should not raise an exception.
>
> Let's make it so.
>
> --
> --Guido van Rossum (python.org/~guido)

Looks like the arguments for removing the exception were stronger in this exchange. Guido van Rossum is the creator of the Python language and had the last word on issues like this. That's why he used to be called [benevolent dicator for life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_dictator_for_life). So after his "Let's make it so", the behaviour was changed so that naive and aware `datetime` object always compare unequal instead of raising a `TypeError`.

Comment: Thank you. This answer actually shows the same "dilemma" I had myself when reflecting about the issue. I tried to find the background about the final decision briefly, but could not find it. Really interesting to see the reasoning and trade-offs being discussed. In the end, I should say I agree with the decision. I will mark this one as the accepted answer as it has more of the context I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

An equality comparison virtually never raises an exception. You just want to know whether object *A* is equal to object *B*, which has a clear answer. If they're equal for however those objects define equality, the answer is *yes*, in all other cases it's *no*. A naïve `datetime` differs from an aware one at least insofar as one has a timezone and the other doesn't, so they're clearly not equal.

For greater-than/lower-than comparisons though, objects clearly need to be orderable, otherwise the question cannot be answered. A `<` comparison can't return `False` just because the objects can't be compared, because that would mean that the opposite `>=` comparison should return `True`, which it also can't. So raising an error in this case is the correct third possible outcome.